# having a problem after added the sqflite in pubspec.yaml and created a database

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, sqflite

Error: Bad state: databaseFactory not initialized
databaseFactory is only initialized when using sqflite. When using `sqflite_common_ffi`
You must call `databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;` before using global openDatabase API
Any solutions please ?
this is my db:

```
`void createDateBase() async
{
  var database = await openDatabase(
    'todo.db',
    version: 1,
    onCreate: (database,version){
      print('database created');
      database.execute('CREATE TABLE tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT,date TEXT,time TEXT,status TEXT)').then((value)
      {print('table created');}).catchError((error)
      {print('${error}');
      });
    },
    onOpen: (datebase){
      print('database opened');
    }
  );
}`
```

i tried to add sqflite web and common ffi , but still with errors , i'm now with only sqflite and got that error ,
i'm expecting to get
database created
table created
database opened